# Error Handling in Python3 - Finding location of specific letters in a list of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, error-handling, letter

I am running into issues getting my code to run through a list of words and list the location of the letters in the list. It works fine in listing location for the first two words, but when it encounters a word without the specified letter, the code skips. I will paste the problem and my current code as well as current output below.

> words = ["dog", "sparrow", "cat", "frog"]
>
> #You may modify the lines of code above, but don't move them!
> #When you Submit your code, we'll change these lines to
> #assign different values to the variables.
>
> #This program is supposed to print the location of the 'o'
> #in each word in the list. However, line 22 causes an
> #error if 'o' is not in the word. Add try/except blocks
> #to print "Not found" when the word does not have an 'o'.
> #However, when the current word does not have an 'o', the
> #program should continue to behave as it does now.
>
> #Hint: don't worry that you don't know how line 18 works.
> #All you need to know is that it may cause an error.
>
> #You may not use any conditionals.
>
> #Fix this code!

**My Code**

```
for word in words:
print(word.index("o"))
```

**Output**

```
1
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FindingO.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(word.index("o"))
ValueError: substring not found
Command exited with non-zero status 1
```

Comment: That's not your code. That's the code from the homework/quiz question.

Comment: my apologies, the code I already have. I am happy to paste all of the different things I have tried, though I don't believe it would be helpful as I can't seem to get it to return to the beginning using an except.

Comment: Check whether there's an 'o' in the word before calling `.index` or explore using `try:` `except:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add try-except block like this:

```
words = ["dog", "sparrow", "cat", "frog"]
for word in words:
    try:
        print(word.index('o'))
    except:
        print("Not found")
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was missing the word pass whenever I tried an except block

Answer (score 1):

Use try and except block to get the position of letters in the word.

```
for letter in words:
try:
    print(letter.index("o"))
except:
    print("not found")
    pass
```